# What are the origins of the Raven Queen?

Tags: dnd-4e, religions-and-deities

What is known of the Raven Queen's origins?

Citing sources is a plus.

Comment: are you looking for in-game D&D references, or real-world mythological references - or both?

Comment: I was looking for D&D references.  I wasn't aware there was a real-world mythological figure known as the Raven Queen.

Comment: Hey Judd! What are you trying to represent with the 'fluff' tag? I see a 'fluff' tag as a personal viewpoint and hard to define in any meaningful way that isn't meta-tagging. (See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/ as to why meta-tags are mostly bad.) Do you disagree?

Comment: I do disagree.  She is a new addition to the D&D mythology, along with Githyanki, beholders, Pelor and Vecna.  They are all D&D fluff or color, as in bits of the setting that are not mechanical in nature.  Other 4e fluff bits: The Primordials, the Shadowfell, etc.

Comment: @Judd: Hmmm... For me `religion-and-deities` covers "color text" and "part of the setting and mostly non-mechanical in nature" while being a specific description of the content. (And one person's `fluff` could be another's silver.)

Comment: That said, I'll leave any further changes alone. `:)`

Comment: I don't see fluff as a negative word. I see it as fiction bits that don't have mechanical weight in play.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For a D&D reference I'll point you to the related [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raven_Queen) (it bears a good summary of the Raven's Queen back history).

For a real-world mythological reference, [this post](http://abutterflydreaming.com/2008/07/27/seeking-the-raven-queen/) goes to a fairly good level of analysis on Greek and Norse mythologies.

Answer (score 6):

Manual of the Planes has a large number of references and on page 60 give some details on her realm.

Open Graves: Secrets of the Undead also gives a lot of information scattered thorugh out it's pages.  Page 22-23 has a whole section write up on her.